# vba outlook embed image with variables

Tags: vb.net, post, outlook, add-in

```
Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    If Not (mailItem Is Nothing) Then
        If mailItem.EntryID Is Nothing Then
            mailItem.Subject = "Test"
            mailItem.HTMLBody = mailItem.HTMLBody + "<html><img src='http://example.com/pixel.php></html>"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The above works fine. But when i try and add some variables to the image i get the following error

> Error! Filename not specified.

Here is my code when trying to add a variable:

```
Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    If Not (mailItem Is Nothing) Then
        If mailItem.EntryID Is Nothing Then
            mailItem.Subject = "Test"
            mailItem.HTMLBody = mailItem.HTMLBody + "<html><img src='http://example.com/pixel.php?to=" + mailItem.To + "></html>"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your single quote (how did this work without it?)

```
"<html><img src='http://example.com/pixel.php></html>"
                ^
```

So the other HTML becomes

```
"<html><img src='http://example.com/pixel.php?to=" + mailItem.To + "'></html>"
                                                                    ^
```